# Tournament data structure

Tags: c

I have written a generic code for implementing a [Tournament](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/tournament-tree-and-binary-heap/) with c language.
i have written all the documentation with Doxygen standard and kept it  in header file, also I have written a unit test with CUnit framework. I am attaching all the files below.

**tournament.h**

```
/**
 * @file tournament.h
 * @author praveen kumar
 * @date 26 sept 2017
 * @brief Tournament Data Structure.
 *
 * The data structure Tournament, as the name signifies, is a knock out tournament
 * of objects/elements of same data type where it is characterized by rounds. every
 * round, except the last one where we are left with the winner only, consist of set of
 * objects. only the winners from the previous round proceed in the next round.<br>
 * <br>
 * The library is flexible to be used for any data type and have several of functions for
 * manipulating the tournament.for the matter of usecase, the first call to a
 * function&nbsp;(during&nbsp;using&nbsp;this&nbsp;structure) must be a #newTournament and must end
 * with a call to #finishTournament, failing to do so may result in inconsistency or
 * memory leak.
 */

#ifndef _tournament_h
#define _tournament_h

/**
 * @brief Abstract data type for a Tournament data structure.
 *
 * typedef-ed for a pointer to a internally maintained structure for the tournament.
 */
typedef struct tournament *Tournament;

struct tournament {
    struct tournam *tourn;
    void *temp;
};

/**
 * @brief Constructor for dynamically allocating a space for the Tournament.
 *
 * @param sizeofPlayer Size of the player(in bytes) or the object taking part in a
 *                     tournament. @c sizeof operator can be useful here for determining
 *                     the size of the object in bytes.
 * @param noOfPlayers Total no of players or objects taking part in the Tournament in the
                      initial phase.
 * @return Tournament Immutable Pointer to a allocated space for the tournament to take place
 *                    or @c NULL if the request for allocation fails.
 *
 * @note Its an error&nbsp;(Dereferencing&nbsp;the&nbsp;incomplete&nbsp;type) if the pointer
 *       returned by this function is dereferenced, there are getters provided by this library
 *       in order to fetch any attribute if needed.
 */
extern Tournament newTournament(size_t sizeofPlayer, uint32_t noOfPlayers);

/**
 * @brief Starts the Tournament.
 *
 * The tournament starts with the players or objects residing in the memory pointed by @p base
 * where a policy for win or loose between players is decided by the @p comp. Call to this function
 * guarantee the completion of all the rounds to be held(depending on the no of players participating).
 * @param tour Pointer to a space allocated for tournament to be held, this pointer must be the one
 *             returned by #newTournament.
 * @param base Pointer to a memory holding the players/elements taking part in the tournament.
 * @param comp pointer to a comparator function for evaluating a loss or win among players.
 * @return Tournament a pointer to a memory holding the tournament structure after completion of rounds
 *                    or @c NULL if either of the parameter passed is @c NULL.
 */
extern Tournament setupTour(Tournament tour, void *base,
                            int (*comp)(const void *, const void *));

/**
 * @brief Useful for viewing the winner of the Tournament @p tour.
 *
 * The function returns a flexible pointer, so its the responsibility of the user of this library to
 * correctly cast the result. For the consistent result the type of the cast must be the type of the
 * players pointed by @p base, which is passed as a parameter in #setupTour.
 * @param tour Tournament for which the winner is to be evaluated.
 * @return void* pointer to a winner and @c NULL if @p tour is @c NULL.
 * @note Their is not any effect of changing the value(through dereferencing) in the memory pointed by
 *       the pointer returned here on the actual data structure, however changing the value is not
 *       accompanied.
 */
extern void *getWinner(Tournament tour);

/**
 * @brief Useful for viewing the Next winner of the Tournament @p tour.
 *
 * Please note the next winner can be different from a runner up. next winner means that this
 * element will loose to the winner only and win against all the other tournament players. since this
 * element might have loose to the winner in the initial rounds their is a good possibility for be it
 * the runner up.<br>
 * The function returns a flexible pointer, so its the responsibility of the user of this library to
 * correctly cast the result. For the consistent result the type of the cast must be the type of the
 * players pointed by @p base, which is passed as a parameter in #setupTour.
 * @param tour Tournament for which the winner is to be evaluated.
 * @return void* pointer to a next winner and @c NULL if @p tour is @c NULL.
 * @note Their is not any effect of changing the value(through dereferencing) in the memory pointed by
 *       the pointer returned here on the actual data structure, however changing the value is not
 *       accompanied.
 */
extern void *getNextWinner(Tournament tour);

/**
 * @brief Useful for viewing the element at arbitrary position in a Tournament.
 * The function returns a flexible pointer, so its the responsibility of the user of this library to
 * correctly cast the result. For the consistent result the type of the cast must be the type of the
 * players pointed by @p base, which is passed as a parameter in #setupTour.
 * @param tour Tournament for which the element is to be evaluated.
 * @param i index of the element in the tournament, which conventionally starts from @c 0 and must end
 *          at a value <tt>2 * getNoOfPlayers(tour) - 2</tt>.
 * @return void* pointer to a element at index @c i or @c NULL if @p tour is @c NULL
 * @note Their is not any effect of changing the value(through dereferencing) in the memory pointed by
 *       the pointer returned here on the actual data structure, however changing the value is not
 *       accompanied.
 */
extern void *getElemAt(Tournament tour, uint16_t i);

/**
 * Useful for evaluating total no of objects or players who had participated in the initial phase of
 * tournament(i.e.. round one).
 * @param tour where the players or objects have participated.
 * @return int the total no of players participating in the tournament @c tour or @c -1 if the @c tour
 *             is @c NULL.
 */
extern int getNoOfPlayers(Tournament tour);

/**
 * @brief Prints the complete tournament in the sequence from winner to the initial phase i.e.. round one.
 *
 * The total no of elements printed are one less than the twice of the initial no of players or elements in
 * the tournament in the initial phase. if we see the view of this printing round wise then it depends upon
 * either the initial no of players are either odd or even. we will start from end. lets see the example:
 * @verbatim CASE: Even
 * Lets suppose we have an array of integers as {8, 7, 15, 1, 6, 9, 4, 3} then the play
 * begins from end i.e.. 3 and 4 will be paired to play, 9 and 6 will be paired to play
 * and so on, our comparator is the max of 2 values. the winners will proceed in round
 * two according to the comparator and are put in front of the round 1 elements,
 * as shown below:
 * {8, 15, 9, 4, 8, 7, 15, 1, 6, 9, 4, 3}, here {8, 15, 9, 4} are round 2 elements
 * the same process will continue among round two elements to get to round Three and so on.
 * finally we will be left with the single element which is the winner and the complete
 * structure looks as:
 * {15, 15, 9, 8, 15, 9, 4, 8, 7, 15, 1, 6, 9, 4, 3} 15 is the winner.
CASE: odd
 * This time take the example: {8, 7, 15, 1, 6, 9, 4}
 * we will proceed in the same way as we do earlier, only the difference is we are left
 * with 1 element in round 1 having not any pair, so this element will be moved to round
 * two without any comparison and the view looks as:
 * {15, 6, 9, 8, 7, 15, 1, 6, 9, 4}
 * please note 8 is not put twice and is shared among round one and two for the view purpose
 * and so we will move further as we did. finally complete structure looks as:
 * {15, 15, 9, 15, 6, 9, 8, 7, 15, 1, 6, 9, 4} 15 is the winner.@endverbatim
 * @param tour tournament to be printed.
 * @param toString pointer to a function providing the string(of characters) view of the player.
 * @param buffer pointer to a memory that will hold the string representation of player returned by @p toString
 * @return void
 *
 */
extern void printTour(Tournament tour, char *(*toString)(const void *elem,
                      char *buffer), char *buffer);

/**
 * @brief Clears all the memory owned by this library.
 *
 * This must be a last function called during utilising this library.
 * @param tour tournament to be freed. their is no effect if @c NULL is passed as parameters.
 * @return void
 * @note @p tour must be a pointer returned by the call to #newTournament.
 *          if this function is called twice on the same Tournament then their is a chance of
 *          inconsistency for the underlying program and it may crash.
 */

extern void finishTournament(Tournament tour);

#endif
```

**tournament.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "headers/tournament.h"

struct tournam {
    uint32_t size;
    size_t sizeofPlayer;
    void *tourTree;
};

static int (*compa)(const void *, const void *);

static Tournament play(Tournament tour,
                       int (*comp)(const void *, const void *));

static void setElemAt(Tournament tour, uint16_t i);

Tournament newTournament(size_t sizeofPlayer, uint32_t noOfPlayers) {
    if (sizeofPlayer == 0 || noOfPlayers == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    Tournament tour = (struct tournament *) malloc(sizeof(struct tournament));
    tour->temp = malloc(sizeofPlayer);
    tour->tourn = (struct tournam *) malloc(sizeof(struct tournam));
    tour->tourn->tourTree = malloc((2 * noOfPlayers - 1) * sizeofPlayer);
    if (tour == NULL || tour->tourn == NULL || tour->temp == NULL
            || tour->tourn->tourTree == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    tour->tourn->size = noOfPlayers;
    tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer = sizeofPlayer;
    return tour;
}

Tournament setupTour(Tournament tour, void *base,
                     int (*comp)(const void *, const void *)) {
    if (tour == NULL || base == NULL
            || comp == NULL) return NULL;
    compa = comp;
    uint32_t i;
    char *_base = (char *) base;
    char * _tourTree = (char *) (tour->tourn->tourTree);
    _tourTree = _tourTree + ((tour->tourn->size - 1) * tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer);
    for (i = 0; i < tour->tourn->size * tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer; i++) {
        *_tourTree++ = *_base++;
    }
    tour = play(tour, comp);
    return tour;
}

static Tournament play(Tournament tour,
                       int (*comp)(const void *, const void *)) {
    for (uint32_t  i = 2 * tour->tourn->size - 2; i > 0; i = i - 2) {
        char *j, *k;
        char *p;
        j = ((char *)(tour->tourn->tourTree) + (i * tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer));
        k = ((char *)(tour->tourn->tourTree) + ((i - 1) * tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer));
        p =  ((char *)(tour->tourn->tourTree) + (((i * tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer) / 2) -
                tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer));
        if ((*comp)(j, k) > 0) {
            for (uint32_t  h = 0; h < tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer; h++) {
                *(p + h) = *(j + h);
            }
        } else {
            for (uint32_t  h = 0; h < tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer; h++) {
                *(p + h) = *(k + h);
            }
        }
    }
    return tour;
}

static void setElemAt(Tournament tour, uint16_t i) {
    char *p = ((char *) tour->tourn->tourTree) + i * tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer;
    for (uint16_t j = 0; j < tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer; j++) {
        *(((char *) tour->temp) + j) = *(p + j);
    }
    return;
}

static void setNextWinner(Tournament tour) {
    char *next, *i, *j;
    i = ((char *) tour->tourn->tourTree) + tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer;
    j = i + tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer;
    if ((*compa)((void *)i, (void *)j) > 0) {
        next = j;
    } else {
        next = i;
        i = j;
    }
    char *k = ((char *)tour->tourn->tourTree) + ((2 * tour->tourn->size - 2) *
              tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer);
    while (1) {
        if ((i = i + 2 * tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer) > k) break;
        if ((*compa)(tour->tourn->tourTree, (void *)i) > 0) {
            if ((*compa)((void *)i, (void *)next) > 0) {
                next = (void *) i;
            }
        } else {
            i = i + tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer;
            if (i > k) break;
            if ((*compa)((void *)i, next) > 0) {
                next = (void *) i;
            }
        }
    }
    for (uint16_t m = 0; m < tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer; m++) {
        *(((char *) tour->temp) + m) = *(next + m);
    }
    return;
}

int getNoOfPlayers(Tournament tour) {
    if (tour == NULL) return -1;
    else
        return tour->tourn->size;
}

void *getWinner(Tournament tour) {
    if (tour == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    setElemAt(tour, 0);
    return tour->temp;
}

void *getNextWinner(Tournament tour) {
    if (tour == NULL || tour->tourn->size <= 1 || compa == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    setNextWinner(tour);
    return tour->temp;
}

void *getElemAt(Tournament tour, uint16_t i) {
    if (tour == NULL || i >= 2 * tour->tourn->size - 1) {
        return NULL;
    }
    setElemAt(tour, i);
    return tour->temp;
}

void printTour(Tournament tour, char *(*toString)(const void *elem,
               char *buffer), char *buffer) {
    if (tour == NULL || toString == NULL || buffer == NULL) {
        printf("EMPTY TOURNAMENT\n");
        return;
    }
    uint32_t i;
    for (i = 0; i < 2 * tour->tourn->size - 1; i++) {
        printf("%s ", (*toString)((char *)(tour->tourn->tourTree) +
                                  (i * tour->tourn->sizeofPlayer),
                                  buffer));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return;
}

void finishTournament(Tournament tour) {
    if (tour == NULL) return;
    free(tour->tourn->tourTree);
    free(tour->tourn);
    free(tour->temp);
    free(tour);
    return;
}
```

**Unit test with CUnit**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "headers/tournament.h"
#include <CUnit/Basic.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE1 sizeof(int)
#define NPLAYERS1 0
#define WINNER1 NULL
#define NEXT_WINNER_NULL NULL

#define NPLAYERS2   2
#define WINNER2     8
#define NEXTWINNER2 7

#define NPLAYERS3   1
#define WINNER3     8

#define NPLAYERS4   8
#define WINNER4     15
#define NEXTWINNER4 9

#define NPLAYERS5   9
#define WINNER5     -4
#define NEXTWINNER5 -10

#define NPLAYERS6   9
#define WINNER6     -4
#define NEXTWINNER6 5

#define SIZE2 sizeof(char *)
#define NPLAYERS7   6
#define WINNER7     "WORLD"
#define NEXTWINNER7 "UNITTESTING"

#define SIZE3 sizeof(struct userType)
#define NPLAYERS8   6

static Tournament tour1 = NULL;
static void *base1 = NULL ;

static Tournament tour2 = NULL;
static int base2[] = {8, 7} ;
static int tournament2[] = {8, 8, 7};

static Tournament tour3 = NULL;
static int base3[] = {8};
static int tournament3[] = {8};

static Tournament tour4 = NULL;
static int base4[] = {8, 7, 15, 1, 6, 9, 4, 3} ;
static int tournament4[] = {15, 15, 9, 8, 15, 9, 4, 8, 7, 15, 1, 6, 9, 4, 3};

static Tournament tour5 = NULL;
static int base5[] = {-4, -12, -11, -16, -17, -10, -20, -108, -201};
static int tournament5[] = {-4, -4, -10, -4, -11, -16, -10, -108, -4, -12, -11, -16, -17, -10, -20, -108, -201};

static Tournament tour6 = NULL;
static int base6[] = {-4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 18, 101, 786};
static int tournament6[] = {-4, -4, 8, -4, 5, 8, 10, 101, -4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 18, 101, 786};

static Tournament tour7 = NULL;
static char *base7[] = {"HELLO", "WORLD", "ONE", "TWO", "TOURNAMENT", "UNITTESTING"};
static char *tournament7[] = {"WORLD", "UNITTESTING", "WORLD", "TWO", "UNITTESTING", "HELLO", "WORLD", "ONE", "TWO", "TOURNAMENT", "UNITTESTING"};

typedef struct userType {
    char name[10];
    int id;
} UserType;

const struct userType WINNER8     = {.name = "C#", .id = 1244};
const struct userType NEXTWINNER8 = {.name = "java", .id = 1239};

static Tournament tour8 = NULL;
static UserType base8[] = {
    {.name = "C language", .id = 1234},
    {.name = "C++", .id = 1235},
    {.name = "java", .id = 1239},
    {.name = "python", .id = 1237},
    {.name = "Lua", .id = 1236},
    {.name = "C#", .id = 1244}
};
static UserType tournament8[] = {
    {.name = "C#", .id = 1244},
    {.name = "C#", .id = 1244},
    {.name = "C++", .id = 1235},
    {.name = "java", .id = 1239},
    {.name = "C#", .id = 1244},
    {.name = "C language", .id = 1234},
    {.name = "C++", .id = 1235},
    {.name = "java", .id = 1239},
    {.name = "python", .id = 1237},
    {.name = "Lua", .id = 1236},
    {.name = "C#", .id = 1244}
};

int init_suite1(void) {
    if ((tour1 = newTournament(SIZE1, NPLAYERS1)) != NULL
            || (tour2 = newTournament(SIZE1, NPLAYERS2)) == NULL
            || (tour3 = newTournament(SIZE1, NPLAYERS3)) == NULL
            || (tour4 = newTournament(SIZE1, NPLAYERS4)) == NULL
            || (tour5 = newTournament(SIZE1, NPLAYERS5)) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int init_suite2(void) {
    if ((tour6 = newTournament(SIZE1, NPLAYERS6)) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int init_suite3(void) {
    if ((tour7 = newTournament(SIZE2, NPLAYERS7))) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int init_suite4(void) {
    if ((tour8 = newTournament(SIZE3, NPLAYERS8)) == NULL) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}


int clean_suite1(void) {
    finishTournament(tour1);
    finishTournament(tour2);
    finishTournament(tour3);
    finishTournament(tour4);
    finishTournament(tour5);
    return 0;
}

int clean_suite2(void) {
    finishTournament(tour6);
    return 0;
}

int clean_suite3(void) {
    finishTournament(tour7);
    return 0;
}

int clean_suite4(void) {
    finishTournament(tour8);
    return 0;
}

int comp_max(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *((int *)a) > *((int *)b) ? 1 : 0;
}

int comp_min(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return *((int *)a) < *((int *)b) ? 1 : 0;
}

int comp_str(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp(*((char **)a), *((char **)b));
}

int comp_usert(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return ((struct userType *)a)->id > ((struct userType *)b)->id;
}

static int usert_equals(const struct userType a, const struct userType b) {
    return (strcmp(a.name, b.name) == 0 && a.id == b.id);
}

void testSetupTour(void) {
    tour1 = setupTour(tour1, base1, comp_max);
    CU_ASSERT_PTR_EQUAL(NULL, tour1);
    tour1 = setupTour(tour1, base1, NULL);
    CU_ASSERT_PTR_EQUAL(NULL, tour1);
    tour2 = setupTour(tour2, base2, comp_max);
    if (tour2 != NULL) {
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 2 * NPLAYERS2 - 1; i++) {
            CU_ASSERT(tournament2[i] == *((int *) getElemAt(tour2, i)));
        }
    }
    tour3 = setupTour(tour3, base3, comp_max);
    if (tour3 != NULL) {
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 2 * NPLAYERS3 - 1; i++) {
            CU_ASSERT(tournament3[i] == *((int *) getElemAt(tour3, i)));
        }
    }
    tour4 = setupTour(tour4, base4, comp_max);
    if (tour4 != NULL) {
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 2 * NPLAYERS4 - 1; i++) {
            CU_ASSERT(tournament4[i] == *((int *) getElemAt(tour4, i)));
        }
    }
    tour5 = setupTour(tour5, base5, comp_max);
    if (tour5 != NULL) {
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 2 * NPLAYERS5 - 1; i++) {
            CU_ASSERT(tournament5[i] == *((int *) getElemAt(tour5, i)));
        }
    }
}

void testSetupTour2(void) {
    tour6 = setupTour(tour6, base6, comp_min);
    if (tour6 != NULL) {
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 2 * NPLAYERS6 - 1; i++) {
            CU_ASSERT(tournament6[i] == *((int *) getElemAt(tour6, i)));
        }
    }
}

void testSetupTour3(void) {
    tour7 = setupTour(tour7, base7, comp_str);
    if (tour7 != NULL) {
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 2 * NPLAYERS7 - 1; i++) {
            CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL(tournament7[i], *((char **) getElemAt(tour7, i)));
        }
    }
}

void testSetupTour4(void) {
    tour8 = setupTour(tour8, base8, comp_usert);
    if (tour8 != NULL) {
        for (uint16_t i = 0; i < 2 * NPLAYERS8 - 1; i++) {
            CU_ASSERT(usert_equals(tournament8[i], *((struct userType *) getElemAt(tour8,
                                   i))));
        }
    }
}

void testgetWinner(void) {
    CU_ASSERT_PTR_EQUAL(WINNER1, (int *) getWinner(tour1));
    CU_ASSERT(WINNER2 == *((int *)getWinner(tour2)));
    CU_ASSERT(WINNER3 == *((int *)getWinner(tour3)));
    CU_ASSERT(WINNER4 == *((int *)getWinner(tour4)));
    CU_ASSERT(WINNER5 == *((int *)getWinner(tour5)));
}

void testgetWinner2(void) {
    CU_ASSERT(WINNER6 == *((int *)getWinner(tour6)));
}

void testgetWinner3(void) {
    CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL(WINNER7, *((char **)getWinner(tour7)));
}

void testgetWinner4(void) {
    CU_ASSERT(usert_equals(WINNER8, *((struct userType *)getWinner(tour8))));
}

void testgetNextWinner(void) {
    CU_ASSERT_PTR_EQUAL(NEXT_WINNER_NULL, ((int *) getNextWinner(tour1)));
    CU_ASSERT(NEXTWINNER2 == *((int *)getNextWinner(tour2)));
    CU_ASSERT_PTR_EQUAL(NEXT_WINNER_NULL, ((int *) getNextWinner(tour3)));
    CU_ASSERT(NEXTWINNER4 == *((int *)getNextWinner(tour4)));
    CU_ASSERT(NEXTWINNER5 == *((int *)getNextWinner(tour5)));
}

void testgetNextWinner2(void) {
    CU_ASSERT(NEXTWINNER6 == *((int *)getNextWinner(tour6)));
}

void testgetNextWinner3(void) {
    CU_ASSERT_STRING_EQUAL(NEXTWINNER7, *((char **)getNextWinner(tour7)));
}

void testgetNextWinner4(void) {
    CU_ASSERT(usert_equals(NEXTWINNER8, *((struct userType*)getNextWinner(tour8))));
}

int main() {
    CU_pSuite pSuite1 = NULL;
    CU_pSuite pSuite2 = NULL;
    CU_pSuite pSuite3 = NULL;
    CU_pSuite pSuite4 = NULL;
    if (CUE_SUCCESS != CU_initialize_registry()) {
        return CU_get_error();
    }
    pSuite1 = CU_add_suite("Suite1", init_suite1, clean_suite1);
    pSuite2 = CU_add_suite("Suite2", init_suite2, clean_suite2);
    pSuite3 = CU_add_suite("Suite3", init_suite3, clean_suite3);
    pSuite4 = CU_add_suite("Suite4", init_suite4, clean_suite4);
    if (pSuite1 == NULL || pSuite2 == NULL || pSuite3 == NULL || pSuite4 == NULL ) {
        CU_cleanup_registry();
        return CU_get_error();
    }
    if (NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite1, "test of setupTour()", testSetupTour)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite1, "test of getWinner()", testgetWinner)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite1, "test of getNextWinner()", testgetNextWinner)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite2, "test of setupTour()", testSetupTour2)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite2, "test of getWinner()", testgetWinner2)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite2, "test of getNextWinner()", testgetNextWinner2)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite3, "test of setupTour()", testSetupTour3)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite3, "test of getWinner()", testgetWinner3)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite3, "test of getNextWinner()", testgetNextWinner3)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite4, "test of setupTour()", testSetupTour4)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite4, "test of getWinner()", testgetWinner4)
            || NULL == CU_add_test(pSuite4, "test of getNextWinner()",
                                   testgetNextWinner4)) {
        CU_cleanup_registry();
        return CU_get_error();
    }
    CU_basic_set_mode(CU_BRM_VERBOSE);
    CU_basic_run_tests();
    CU_cleanup_registry();
    return CU_get_error();
}
```

Please share the improvements/optimizations related with design, algorithm, testing etc that to my code.

Comment: Global identifiers starting with an underscore are reserved for the implementation.

Comment: `struct tournament {
    struct tournam *tourn;
    void *temp;
};` not needed in `tournament.h`, just `tournament.c`

Comment: Well if i do not maintain a opaque pointer in header i will get lots of error can you elaborate some more on it..might be i am missing something..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some things that may help you improve your software.  It seems nicely structured and commented.

### Use the required `#include`s

The code uses `uint32_t` which means that it should `#include <stdint.h>`.  It was not difficult to infer, but it helps reviewers if the code is complete.  Also, `size_t` also needs an include.  See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t

### Fix the bug

The test code currently contains this function:

```
int init_suite3(void) {
    if ((tour7 = newTournament(SIZE2, NPLAYERS7))) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

That's an error.  The `if` should be this instead:

```
if ((tour7 = newTournament(SIZE2, NPLAYERS7)) == NULL) {
```

### Proofread the comments

Although there are a lot of comments, and the idea of documenting with Doxygen is a good one, I find that the comments don't really help me understand the program.  For example, the documentation for `getWinner()` has this utterly confusing note:

> Please note the next winner can be different from a runner up. next winner means that this element will loose to the winner only and win against all the other tournament players. since this element might have loose to the winner in the initial rounds their is a good possibility for be it the runner up.

First, I think you meant "lose" instead of "loose" but even with that change, I still can't parse this sentence and have no idea what it was intending to convey.

What the reader of this documentation really needs to know is *what the function does* which, curiously, is not part of the documentation at the moment.

### Use better naming

We have `newTournament` which seems like a good enough name, but `setupTour` is not.  First, "Tour" is an unfortunate abbreviation for "Tournament" that is easily misconstrued.  Second, and most important, "set up" implies a configuration, after which some action is taken, but what it really does is actually run the whole tournament to its conclusion.  A more intuitive name might have been `runTournament` instead.  Also, it might be better to prefix all of the API functions with the same prefix, as perhaps `Tournament_new`, `Tournament_run`, `Tournament_free`, etc.

### Consider expanding testing

The `printTour` routine is never actually tested.  It might be a good idea to make sure that all of the functions are tested.  What you have is a really nice start.

### Provide a full working example

This comment is really more about how to get a good code review rather than about the code itself.  While the CUnit test is good, an example showing a small but complete example would be useful not only as documentation for users but also for reviewers.